# ScaleOut vs Ncache?

Tags: ncache

I'm evaluating both these third-party vendors for distributed cache. Has anyone already compared them and formed an opinion on which is better?

Answer (score 11):

I just came this post and would like to add that I am an old user of NCache and have a very good expereince with the working and performance of this product.

William L. Bain's post was meant to give differences between the two reputed caching solutions but I dont see any mention about NCache so here are some features of NCache that probably will make it distinct from ScaleOut.

1. NCache offers partioned-replica cache that gives you scalability through partitioning, reliability through replication and availability of data against data loss and node failure. You also have the option to use replicated, partitioned, local , client or mirror cache with NCache
2. NCache allows you use read and write-through so that you can be sure your cache is never out of sync from database.
3. With the Bulk operations features, you can combine multiple get or write calls, this reduces bandwidth consumptions and the operation is much faster than making many individual get or write calls.
4. Event and polling based synchronization
5. Object queries
6. Pre-load cache with data
7. Auto-start of cache on windows startup
8. NCache also gives NHibernate support
9. Client cache for faster results. The client cache sits with the application and hold most frequent used data. The client cache is synced with the master cache and  provides efficient and better read/write results
10. Enahnced security features

NCache is also great for ASP.NET sessions. It lets you cache your session-state in cache without needing any code change. All you need is to modify Web.config and you are ready to use caching for your ASP.NET application.

NCache comes with a monitoring utility called NCache Monitor that lets you see Topology used, cache uptime, items count, port no, events history and more.
The NCache Manager (a GUI tool for managing caches) also integrates a statitics window where you can monitor real-time cache activity including evictions, additions, reads, writes, updates, expirations, read and write through requests and more.

Comment: And it's now open-sourced!